# sum of all subgroup elements

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

1.start from multiplicative group modulus N where N is odd.
2.take all elements of subgroup with generator equal 2.

question : what do you need to know about N
(factorization,phi)  for fast calculation of total sum
of all subgroup elements.

known facts :
it is easy to prove  , it equal to K*N

it is somehow related to phi(N)

related problems : number of odd elements,
number of elements less than (N-1)/2.0
difference between number of odd and even elements - in most cases is not 0.

how calculate K?

example : 35
1,2,4,8,16,32,29,23,11,22,9,18 = 175 = 5*35
even : 7,odd : 5 , 7-5=2

is it related somehow to modular functions(forms)?

fast  : O(log n) or something similar ,O(phi(n)) Is very slow.

Comment: I think even if $N$ is prime you need to know the order of $2$ modulo $N$, and there's no known fast way to compute that.

Comment: if $N$ is prime, factorization of $N-1$ is not “slow” problem.Then just check division 2 ** factors - 1 by $N$

Comment: If the equation $2^j\equiv -1$ (mod $n$) has a solution, then $k=\frac 12 \mathrm{ord}_n(2)$, where $\mathrm{ord}_n(2)$ denotes the order of 2 modulo $n$. This is because the powers of 2 come in pairs $c,n-c$.

Comment: @user6690 The equation $2^j\equiv -1$ (mod 35) does not have a solution, so $n=35$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: thank you, but it is trivial case - odd == even.

N = 35, no solution.

Comment: I would say , the most interesting number for me  is difference between  odd and even  :number which is "free" from order of group, for small N it has some connections with quadratic class number ,later  they diverge...

Comment: I have  checked many Ns, I have hypothesis : any difference between odd and even  is possible for some N, how it can be proved?

Comment: and question with * : what is the limit when N -> inf =  number_of _Ns_where(number of even > number of odd)/number_of _Ns_where(number of even <= number of odd)
is it 1? ...574983 15362 15466 104 *0.861205*